# Perl : Error 500 Cant Connect Certificate Verify Failed

Tags: perl

I have problem when I try to running Perl script using PHP, below is the Perl Script

```
use HandlePWRequestService;

my $certfile = "E:\perl\Cache-UserMySQL.p12";
my $certpw = "Welcome1";
my $system = "Test-MySQL";
my $account = "admin1";


#$ENV{'PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAME'} = 0;
#$ENV{HTTPS_CA_DIR} = 'E:\perl';
#$ENV{HTTPS_CA_FILE} = 'E:\perl\parRootCA';
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_FILE} = $certfile;
$ENV{HTTPS_PKCS12_PASSWORD} = $certpw;
$ENV{HTTPS_DEBUG} = 1;

my $pwservice = new HandlePWRequestService;
my @rc = $pwservice->handleRequestWS($system,$account);
print "rc=$rc[0], password=$rc[1]\n";
```

And whenever I try run I got error `500 Certificate Verify Failed`.
I wonder what might cause this?

Below is the code for HandlePWRequestService
HandlePWRequestService.pm

```
package HandlePWRequestService;

my %methods = (
handleRequestWS => {
endpoint => 'https://some_ip/HandlePWRequestService/HandlePWRequest',
soapaction => '',
namespace => 'http://ejb3.pwAccel.edmz.com/',
parameters => [
  SOAP::Data->new(name => 'systemName', type => 'xsd:string', attr => {}),
  SOAP::Data->new(name => 'accountName', type => 'xsd:string', attr => {}),
], # end parameters
  }, # end handleRequestWS
 ); # end my %methods

use SOAP::Lite;
use Exporter;
use Carp ();

use vars qw(@ISA $AUTOLOAD @EXPORT_OK %EXPORT_TAGS);
@ISA = qw(Exporter SOAP::Lite);
@EXPORT_OK = (keys %methods);
%EXPORT_TAGS = ('all' => [@EXPORT_OK]);

sub _call {
    my ($self, $method) = (shift, shift);
    my $name = UNIVERSAL::isa($method => 'SOAP::Data') ? $method->name :    $method;
    my %method = %{$methods{$name}};
    $self->proxy($method{endpoint} || Carp::croak "No server address (proxy) specified")
    unless $self->proxy;
my @templates = @{$method{parameters}};
my @parameters = ();
foreach my $param (@_) {
    if (@templates) {
        my $template = shift @templates;
        my ($prefix,$typename) = SOAP::Utils::splitqname($template->type);
        my $method = 'as_'.$typename;
        # TODO - if can('as_'.$typename) {...}
        my $result = $self->serializer->$method($param, $template->name, $template->type, $template->attr);
        push(@parameters, $template->value($result->[2]));
    }
    else {
        push(@parameters, $param);
    }
}
$self->endpoint($method{endpoint})
   ->ns($method{namespace})
   ->on_action(sub{qq!"$method{soapaction}"!});
$self->serializer->register_ns("http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd","wsu");
$self->serializer->register_ns("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema","xsd");
$self->serializer->register_ns("http://ejb3.pwAccel.edmz.com/","tns");
$self->serializer->register_ns("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/","soap");
my $som = $self->SUPER::call($method => @parameters);
if ($self->want_som) {
    return $som;
}
 UNIVERSAL::isa($som => 'SOAP::SOM') ? wantarray ? $som->paramsall : $som->result : $som;
 }

 sub BEGIN {
    no strict 'refs';
    for my $method (qw(want_som)) {
    my $field = '_' . $method;
    *$method = sub {
        my $self = shift->new;
        @_ ? ($self->{$field} = shift, return $self) : return $self->{$field};
        }
    }
}
 no strict 'refs';
 for my $method (@EXPORT_OK) {
 my %method = %{$methods{$method}};
     *$method = sub {
    my $self = UNIVERSAL::isa($_[0] => __PACKAGE__)
        ? ref $_[0]
            ? shift # OBJECT
            # CLASS, either get self or create new and assign to self
            : (shift->self || __PACKAGE__->self(__PACKAGE__->new))
        # function call, either get self or create new and assign to self
        : (__PACKAGE__->self || __PACKAGE__->self(__PACKAGE__->new));
    $self->_call($method, @_);
}
 }

sub AUTOLOAD {
my $method = substr($AUTOLOAD, rindex($AUTOLOAD, '::') + 2);
return if $method eq 'DESTROY' || $method eq 'want_som';
die "Unrecognized method '$method'. List of available method(s):   @EXPORT_OK\n";
 }

 1;
```

Comment: The certificate is not correkt

Comment: If I understand correctly, you are trying to avoid embedding passwords in scripts by communicating with a password server where clients authenticate using client certificates. To rule out other possible issues, see if you can use `openssl pkcs12 -in file.p12 -info -noout`  from the command line.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I want to retrieve the password from password server. Regarding your script, yes i can use that command line script. It showed Shrouded Keybag and PKCS7 Encrypted Data

Answer (score 0):

Hard to be sure as HandlePWRequestService seems to be a private module that we can't be expected to know anything about.

But looking at the environment variables that your code is setting, I'd guess that there is some kind of HTTPS interaction going on that probably uses [LWP](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) and friends. So my first recommendation would be to uncomment the line which turns off hostname verification and see if that fixes the problem.

Comment: The HandlePWRequestService is a module to retreive password from back end system by passing system name and Account name. So yes its using HTTPS interaction. And Also i've tried to uncomment it now I got error 500 Cant Connect to some_ip at line 17. But i can access that IP and remote it. I wonder what causing this error.

Comment: I wonder that too. But I'm not telepathic, so I'm not sure how I can help you to debug code that I can't see.

Comment: Ah. SOAP :-( I'm afraid that's the point at which I bow out of the discussion. The only advice I can give about SOAP is to avoid it whenever possible. Good luck.